# Adding interface make weaker hermetization

Tags: java, spring-boot

Consider following example:

```
   class Ccc implements Ttt {
        @Override
        public void pay() {} // must be public
    }

    class Ddd implements Ttt {
        @Override
        public void pay() {} // must be public
    }

    public interface Ttt {
        void pay();
    }
// in same package, but other file:
   class Eee {
    private final EnumMap<SomeEnum, Ttt> strategies = new EnumMap<>(SomeEnum.class);

    Allocate() {
        strategies.put(SomeEnum.CERT, new Ccc());
        strategies.put(SomeEnum.GROUP, new Ddd());
    }
// some other methods using `strategies` Map and method `pay`
}
```

If class `Ccc` and `Ddd` did not implement `Ttt` the method `pay` could be proteced.
In my case method `pay` is used outside of the class `Ccc` and `Ddd`.
But I am using polymorphism in class `Eee` as two classes implement `Ttt` class.

I wonder if it would be better to make the method `pay` protected in some way?
I know i have to prioritze abstraction vs implementation - but i think this is a drawback of it.

Comment: `interface` methods are always `public` - it’s an `interface` after all! However, your `interface` can be package-private as well as your classes then no one outside your package can see it. Make the classes package-private too.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks, as you can see classes are already package scope, they can not be private in my case. But i will make the interface package scope.
I was wondering if it would be better to not use interface at all, and made the method protected maybe?